# Meteor technique/pattern for waiting on a database variable change and then doing something after in

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am creating a Meteor web app that a user can order goods but the user must wait for someone on the backend to change the status of an order.

user submits order , message shows on screen order is pending.

I have a specific order object that has a variable called status which is set to `pending`.

We now have to wait for an admin to change the status to `accepted` or `declined` from the backend.

if the order status is changed to accepted i need to redirect to a order processed page based on the id of the order.

my trouble is i dont know how to wait for the order status to change.

here is what i have at the moment

```
Meteor.call('placeOrder',cartSession,deliveryDetailsId,payment,function(error,result){
      if(error){
          console.log('ERROR :', error);
         }else{
           console.log('response:', result);
           var pendingOrder = Orders.findOne({_id:result});
           console.log("pendingOrder");
           console.log(pendingOrder);
           //the order status of the pendingOrder is 'pending' at this moment
           $('#order-processing').text('order is processing');
           //i must now wait for the status to change to accepted or declined
         }
    });
```

as Marius Darila comment i have added publications of order

```
Meteor.publish('userorders', function () {
  if(this.userId){
    return Orders.find({userId:this.userId});
  }
  this.ready();
});
```

user **cannot** insert , update or remove orders , this only occurs server side

i added this code within my meteor method callback function

```
if(pendingOrder.orderStatus =="accepted"){
    Router.go('/orderProcessed',{orderId:pendingOrder._id})
  }
```

Marius below said that this code would be rerun if the orderStatus changed,
but the code did not run

How Marius Darila helped me answer this question

As i was returning an id from the server of the current user order

i set a `Session.set("orderId", orderId)`

then within a template helper `orderstatus` , we find the current order within the orders db, and we complete our logic within this helper.

if the order is pending show order is pending
when the order is accepted route the user to orderConfirmed page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Db is a reactive source of data so in your client code should have something like this:

```
    var order = Orders.findOne({_id:result});
    if(order.accepted == 1){
        Router.go("someUrlName", {product: order._id});
    }else{
        $('#order-processing').text('order is processing');
   }
```

This example uses iron-router for redirect.

Comment: yes but at that given time when the meteor method returns the order will be `pending` as we are waiting on someone in the backend to accept the order. , what is returned to the customer is the id of the current pending order.

Comment: its that reactivity that i need to wait for, but i don't know how to in this circumstance

Comment: You dont have to do something special. If you update any field of that order, the condition if(order.accepted==1) will be run again.

Comment: Tell me how you handle the pub/sub for Orders, there you may have problems.

Comment: i am going to test the above statement now

Comment: also , i have updated how i handle publication server side in question

Comment: updated my question above, as the above did not work for me when i updated the order status in my db

Comment: on client side you make the Meteor.call("placeorder") in a event handler?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72583/discussion-between-marius-darila-and-molleman).